# Connecting to backend API - Invalid Request first attempt

Tags: swift, api, networking, oauth

I am trying to connect to a customer's database through an API endpoint. When I do GET requests, the first request (or sometimes up to the first 5 requests) results in the error message:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <result>Invalid signature</result>
```

All the credentials are correct. What could be possible causes to this problem? Has anyone experienced this before? Does anyone know any solutions?

Comment: Are you doing XML or JSON parsing?

Comment: That looks like an error message generated by the API and if so you should consult the API documentation or contact the publisher of the API

Comment: I'm using XML parsing.

Comment: Yes, i am agree with @JoakimDanielson